# Jupyter lab/notebook used to be working but now either crashes on opening or cannot open

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Both Jupyter lab and notebook was working on my mac os. Recently after running Jupiter lab in terminal, it returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter-lab", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import NotebookApp, aliases, flags
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 33, in <module>
    ioloop.install()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 210, in install
    assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \
AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'
```

I've tried uninstall tornado and install the latest 6.0.3 version.
I also tried `conda install -c anaconda pyzmq command` but it takes so long to run and never finishes. When the command is running it's showing me a long list of pkg with inconsistencies with the first few lines below

```
Solving environment: |
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
/
  - <unknown>/osx-64::nltk==3.0.2=np19py27_0
  - <unknown>/osx-64::conda-build==1.11.0=py27_0
  - <unknown>/osx-64::dynd-python==0.6.5=np19py27_0
  - <unknown>/osx-64::ipython-qtconsole==3.0.0=py27_0
```

In terms of Jupiter notebook, it keeps crashing (kernel dying) upon opening. I did everything mentioned on this [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892) which seems to solve the problem for many others but not me. This may or may not be related to upgrading to catalina.

Comment: did you tried to remove the four packages mentioned in the error and install them again, so that it installs compatible version?

Comment: it appears I don't even have these few dozen pkgs listed in the msg "WARNING: Skipping conda-build as it is not installed.
 pip3 uninstall dynd-python
WARNING: Skipping dynd-python as it is not installed." Then I  installed conda-build and run the same pyzmq command, same error message.

Comment: install all packages which are being skipped.

Comment: I realized conda is using python 2. I normally use python3 and pip. For this particular conda command 'conda install -c anaconda pyzmq command', how can I make it recognize python3 instead of throwing more than 3 dozen incompatibility msgs. Also tried 'pip3 install pyzmq' which doesn't solve the problem. notebook still won't start.

Comment: you can upgrade python `conda upgrade python` or install specific version`conda install python=3.6`.

Comment: same 3 dozen incompatibility msg when running conda upgrade python. shall i re-install anaconda?

Comment: That would be better or you could create a separate environment `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda`.